# How does jslint work?

Tags: javascript, jslint, pratt-parser

How does jslint check for problems in javascript?  Does it have an actual javascript parser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSLint is [written in JavaScript and uses a Pratt Parser](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#implementation). It "works" by parsing the source provided and looks for "problems". These problems are defined by the author, and are not necessarily syntax-related.

It should be noted that "[JSLint defines a professional subset of JavaScript](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#what)". This means that not all pure ECMAScript would appear valid in JSLint.

Comment: Do you that mean by that, that JSLint's parser doesn't parse every valid ECMA-/JavaScript correctly?

Comment: @fridojet I can't answer that question definitively. The author claims that **"JSLint defines a professional subset of JavaScript, a stricter language than that defined by _[Third Edition of the ECMAScript Programming Language Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)_."**. I understand that to mean it is possible that not all valid ECMAScript programs will be valid from a JSLint perspective. I suppose it would have to be able to parse correctly in order to determine if a given piece of JavaScript is "good" or not, though. You can always ask Crockford :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it parses and analyses the code.

It does not only check for definite problems in the code like syntax errors, but also any potential problems. If you write code that looks strange, there is a big probability that it doesn't do what you intended.